# Proposal: The MP&T "precognitive" badge be retired

Tags: feature-request, badges

As I understand it, the "Precognitive" badge can no longer be earned for Music: Practice and Theory. I suggest to move it to the "Retired" list.

From https://music.stackexchange.com/help/badges

> Followed the Area 51 proposal for this site before it entered the commitment phase

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that all Stack Exchange sites share the same list of badges, and the badge itself isn't retired (like [Tumbleweed](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/badges/40/tumbleweed) is for instance); they continue to be awarded on the [newest sites](https://drones.stackexchange.com/help/badges). Customizable badge lists aren't implemented, [not even for Meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121922/295232) so I doubt your proposal will ever be implemented, but who knows?